# Parse data from another site and display on own site

Tags: database, parsing

If someone wants to create website that parses data from other sites and then sifts through and organizes that data to be displayed, what are the best programming languages, front and back-end, to use in order to achieve this?

(Like searching through Craigslist and displaying the best deals of the day. Or searching through every football teams' roster to display any recent changes.)

Answer (score 0):

A good lawyer. No, seriously, get one, because you can run afoul of copyright fairly easily.

Apart from that, any language that includes good support for parsers and text processing, or ideally processing HTML. XML is too strict. Also, depending on the site, you may need a language with a built-in JavaScript/HTML renderer, because many sites these days use JS to actually load the data into an empty page.